# Warning while restarting the apache2 server

Tags: apache2

When restarting the apache2 server, I'm getting a warning.

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
* Restarting web server apache2
[Tue Sep 02 10:38:54 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Tue Sep 02 10:38:54 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

How do I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there's a misconfiguration in your server.  You want to make sure the values of [`Listen`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#listen), [`NameVirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) and [`VirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) all match.  In your case, I'd expect:

```
Listen *:80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ...
    DocumentRoot ...
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```